# PHP higher versions have any soap issues?

Tags: php, web-services, soap

Kindly find my Xampp version details as below,

PHP: 5.5.30 (old)
PHP: 7.0.9 (new)

I created a website using old php version, now I would like to upgrade my php version. In my site I have web service using by SOAP. While I'm upgrade php version, the wsdl is working but I'm unable to get the data, same like that I'm not get any errors also. Is I need to change my code for version variation? If anyone faced like this issue kindly guide me how to resolve that.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you see in console ?

Comment: Thanks for your response,

In console I'm not getting any error but the data is null. Kindly find the below attachment.

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-hPyr64DgwCw/WMo04MA8uUI/AAAAAAAAANA/C5zG5z_NzzcYR3BrENby3ot3zthCdGNjQCL0B/h590/2017-03-15.png

Comment: Hi all,
After a long time doing R&D finally I found the solution, the issue is with the PHP version 5.6.30. In this version there is a SOAP bug with the PHP code. I contacted the PHP team, they said, some versions of PHP have some bug related to SOAP, and they suggested me to upgrade to higher versions of PHP (7.1.1). I followed the same version that they suggested. And finally I resolved the problem.

Comment: If possible, please post that as the answer. So that it will help the future readers

Answer (score 0):

After a long time doing R&D finally I found the solution, the issue is with the PHP version 5.6.30. In this version there is a SOAP bug with the PHP code. I contacted the PHP team, they said, some versions of PHP have some bug related to SOAP, and they suggested me to upgrade to higher versions of PHP (7.1.1). I followed the same version that they suggested. And finally I resolved the problem.